# CakePHP Fulltext search MySQL with rating

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I've read that, to be able to rank search results you may query MySQL like this:

```
SELECT * , 
MATCH (title, body) AGAINST ('$search') AS rating 
FROM posts 
WHERE MATCH (title, body) AGAINST ('$search') 
ORDER BY rating DESC
```

Is there a way to do this in CakePHP 2.X?
Also, I need to do this while paginating at the same time. So I think I would need to write condition for the paginator, not a direct 'query'.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it took me some time... Since, the key issue was to get a rating on the resulting matches, the complicated part in this query was the specific field:

`MATCH (title, body) AGAINST ('$search') AS rating`

I figured that I should just write that field in the "field" option, in the pagination array.
The resulting code was the following:

```
    $this->paginate = array(
            'limit' => 15,
            'fields' => array('*', "MATCH (data) AGAINST ('$q') AS rating"),
            'conditions' =>  "MATCH(SearchIndex.data) AGAINST('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE)",
            'order' => array(
                'rating' => 'desc',
            ),
    );
    $paginatedResults = $this->paginate('SearchIndex');
```

And that worked seamlessly!

I think this is the best way to achieve real search results using Cake. Unless someone has a better alternative :)

Searching phrases in between double quotes will give you the results you should expect!

Comment: Please see comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/20326527/47573 , without further protection (which isn't clear from the context) this opens your application against SQL injections ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection ).

Comment: You may want to consider making rating a virtualField. This way it will be inside your SearchIndex array. *$this->SearchIndex->virtualFields['rating'] = "MATCH (SearchIndex.data) AGAINST ('".$q."')";*

Comment: Please improve your answer and fix the sql injection

Answer (score 3):

Use like this it will prevent mysql injection too

```
array("MATCH(User.current_position) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)" => $srch_arr['text'])
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used the above database call by Thomas (thank you) and it does work seamlessly.

However the code:

```
'conditions' =>  "MATCH(SearchIndex.data) AGAINST('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE)",
```

removes the Data Abstraction Layer and opens up your site to SQL injection.

It's probably not quite as good (haven't fully tested it) but try:

```
'SearchIndex.data LIKE'=>'%'.$search.'%'
```

I hope this is helpful in someway.