# CakePHP find query using %like%

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have the following find query for my CakePHP app:

```
$this->paginate = array(
'limit'=>5,
'order'=>'Note.datetime DESC',
'conditions' => array(
    'Note.status'=>1,
    'OR' => array(
        'Note.title LIKE' => '%'. $q . '%',
        'Note.content LIKE' => '%'. $q . '%'
        )
    )
);
```

Which takes a parameter called `$q` to do like query on both title and content.

So for example if I have the following:

`Title: Lorem ipsum`
`Content: Lorem ipsum dolare`

And search for `'lorem'`

It would find it fine. But if I search for `'lorem dolare'` it won't find it.

How do I do that?

Note: I don't want to use any plugins etc.

EDIT: If I use FULLTEXT would this work?

```
$this->paginate = array(
'limit'=>5,
'order'=>'Note.datetime DESC',
'conditions' => array(
    'Note.status'=>1,
    'OR' => array(
        'MATCH(Note.title) AGAINST('.$q.' IN BOOLEAN MODE)',
        'MATCH(Note.content) AGAINST('.$q.' IN BOOLEAN MODE)'
        )
    )
);
```

EDIT 2:

Getting this error trying the above:

```
 Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'dolor IN BOOLEAN MODE)) OR (MATCH(`Note`.`content`) AGAINST(lorem dolor IN BOOLE' at line 1

SQL Query: SELECT `Note`.`id`, `Note`.`title`, `Note`.`excerpt`, `Note`.`content`, `Note`.`datetime`, `Note`.`user_id`, `Note`.`slug`, `Note`.`status`, `Note`.`topic_id`, `User`.`id`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`firstname`, `User`.`lastname`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`status`, `Topic`.`id`, `Topic`.`title`, `Topic`.`slug` FROM `db52704_driz2013`.`notes` AS `Note` LEFT JOIN `db52704_driz2013`.`users` AS `User` ON (`Note`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `db52704_driz2013`.`topics` AS `Topic` ON (`Note`.`topic_id` = `Topic`.`id`) WHERE `Note`.`status` = 1 AND ((MATCH(`Note`.`title`) AGAINST(lorem dolor IN BOOLEAN MODE)) OR (MATCH(`Note`.`content`) AGAINST(lorem dolor IN BOOLEAN MODE))) ORDER BY `Note`.`datetime` DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Try removing the first `%`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Still not finding it.

Comment: I was thinking of just what Wayne posted below `FULLTEXT` search. Have a look at this Q&A on SO http://stackoverflow.com/q/17294924/1415724 may help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'limit'=>5,
    'order'=>'Note.datetime DESC',
    'conditions' => array(
        'Note.status'=>1,
        'OR' => array(
            "MATCH(Note.title) AGAINST('".$q."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)",
            "MATCH(Note.content) AGAINST('".$q."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)"
        )
    )
);
```

In other words, enclose the search criteria with quotes

**EDIT ndm's** suggestion makes sense

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'limit'=>5,
    'order'=>'Note.datetime DESC',
    'conditions' => array(
        'Note.status'=>1,
        'OR' => array(
            'MATCH(Note.title) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)' => $q,
            'MATCH(Note.content) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)' => $q
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: It's also a perfectly nice SQL injection vulnerability! ;) Please use the proper [**array syntax**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions) instead: `"MATCH(Post.title) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)" => $q` @Cameron

Comment: @ndm Can you post EXACTLY what you think the whole thing should look like? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can also try this:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'limit'=>5,
    'order'=>'Note.datetime DESC',
    'conditions' => array(
        'Note.status'=>1,
        'OR' => array(
            'Note.title LIKE' => "%$q%",
            'Note.content LIKE' => "%$q%"
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

LIKE won't help you here. Your title is `Lorem ipsum` and your content is `Lorem ipsum dolare`. You're searching for `lorem dolare`, which won't be found via the LIKE operator as it is not a substring inside either of those columns. You'll need to look into using FULLTEXT or you'll need to use something like [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2013/06/26/from-mysql-fulltext-search-to-sphinx/). Take a look at [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1381860/491494) if you're trying to figure out what solution to implement.

Comment: What would you suggest then?

Comment: Could you share an example? I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827444/cakephp-fulltext-search-mysql-with-rating any good for what I want?

Comment: You'll find plenty of examples floating around. I must note that you'll need to use MyISAM if you want to implement FULLTEXT, and that has a few drawbacks. Have a look here before you make a choice: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1381860/491494

Comment: @Cameron You'll have to test. Although in order for FULLTEXT to work, you'll need to change the table from INNODB to MyISAM.

Comment: If your search conditions are somewhat complex then I recommend to use our [plugin](https://github.com/cakedc/search)

Comment: I've tried the code and got a SQL error. Any ideas what the problem is? I've changed the table to MyISAM.

Comment: You're missing single quotes around your $q variable. 'MATCH(Note.title) AGAINST('.$q.' IN BOOLEAN MODE)' should be 'MATCH(Note.title) AGAINST(\''.$q.'\' IN BOOLEAN MODE)' for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please Try this:

$this->paginate = array(
    'limit'=>5,
    'order'=>'Note.datetime DESC',
    'conditions' => array(
        'Note.status'=>1,
        'OR' => array(
            'Note.title LIKE' => "%".$q."%",
            'Note.content LIKE' => "%".$q."%"
        )
    )
);
```